# Cannot access mysql in new docker/docksal/d9 installation

Tags: database

I had a D9 installation running in MacPorts. I installed docker and docksal, copied the D9 project to the docksal project folder, and uninstalled MacPorts.

Docksal starts up like this:

```
Starting services...
Creating network "myproject_default" with the default driver
Starting myproject_db_1  ... done
Starting myproject_cli_1 ... done
Starting myproject_web_1 ... done
Connected vhost-proxy to "myproject_default" network.
```

docker ps yields:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                                    NAMES
13ef8d52170d   docksal/ssh-agent:1.3     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)                                                            docksal-ssh-agent
f68c8343b0fe   docksal/dns:1.1           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:53->53/udp                                       docksal-dns
94854d2add70   docksal/vhost-proxy:1.7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp                 docksal-vhost-proxy
17b4ab7d12dc   docksal/mysql:5.7-1.5     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes (healthy)   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55001->3306/tcp, :::55001->3306/tcp   myproject_db_1
a70ffb3c287a   docksal/apache:2.4-2.3    "httpd-foreground"       34 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes (healthy)   80/tcp, 443/tcp                                          myproject_web_1
7e331d850e06   docksal/cli:php7.4-3.0    "/opt/startup.sh sup…"   34 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes (healthy)   22/tcp, 3000/tcp, 9000/tcp                               myproject_cli_1'
```

but fin drush cr yields:

```
    In Connection.php line 174:
                                                        
      SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  
                                                    
and fin drush sqlc yields:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

In Process.php line 256:
                                                                                                     
  The command "mysql --defaults-file=/tmp/drush_RPHXDD --database=myproj --host=localhost --port=33  
  06 -A" failed.                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
  Exit Code: 1(General error)                                                                        
                                                                                                     
  Working directory: /var/www/docroot                                                                
                                                                                                     
  Output:                                                                                            
  ================                                                                                   
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
  Error Output:                                                                                      
  ================
```

fin drush status:

```
 Drupal version : 9.1.2                                 
 Site URI       : http://myproject.docksal            
 DB driver      : mysql                                 
 DB hostname    : localhost                             
 DB port        : 3306                                  
 DB username    : root                                  
 DB name        : myproj                                
 PHP binary     : /usr/local/bin/php                    
 PHP config     :                                       
 PHP OS         : Linux                                 
 Drush script   : /usr/local/bin/drush                  
 Drush version  : 10.5.0                                
 Drush temp     : /tmp                                  
 Drush configs  : /var/www/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
 Drupal root    : /var/www/docroot                      
 Site path      : sites/default
```

docker logs db:

```
db_1   | Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500160Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500184Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500188Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500192Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500260Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500640Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500647Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500649Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500652Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500654Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500677Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500679Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500686Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500689Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500691Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500692Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500694Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500695Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500697Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500698Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500700Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500701Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500703Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500704Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500706Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500707Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500709Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500710Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500712Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500713Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500714Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500716Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500717Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500719Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500720Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500722Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500723Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500725Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500726Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500728Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500729Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500730Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500732Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500829Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.500933Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.601593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:53.602156Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 210808  5:01:53
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.139112Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12488783
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.147075Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.147420Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.147516Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.147588Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.147917Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.148232Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:01:55.155374Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2021-08-08 05:02:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.30-1debian10 started.
db_1   | 2021-08-08 05:02:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1   | Running init scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ as root...
db_1   | Including custom configuration from /var/www/.docksal/etc/mysql/my.cnf
db_1   | 2021-08-08 05:02:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.30-1debian10 started.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.376939Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.381332Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30) starting as process 1 ...
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.384729Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.384742Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.384744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.384747Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.384749Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.384751Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.385017Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.385113Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.386353Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.490032Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.507421Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.533356Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.618195Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.618496Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.751813Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.777613Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.777675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.810394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.30 started; log sequence number 12488783
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.832602Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.834210Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.898552Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210808  5:02:04
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.914468Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.915086Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.925715Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.926091Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.932524Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.932753Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.932880Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.933009Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:04.950069Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:05.120498Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2021-08-08T05:02:05.134073Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.7.30'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

This is the case whether I have localhost or 127.0.0.1 in settings.php.  Seems the mysql service is there and the container is starting, but nothing can connect to the service.

Comment: Would the DB really be on localhost for a containerised solution? Doesn’t that kind of defeat the purpose?

Comment: I assume localhost to be relative to the container, as is /var/www/html

Comment: They’re different machines so I’m not sure that assumption would hold. Admittedly I haven’t used Docksal (Lando is hard to beat for reliability and ease of use), but I would’ve assumed they work similarly. Especially as both create a network so that the containers can communicate with one another, which would be unnecessary if they’re reachable by the same host name

Comment: You’re correct. I ran the install again, with a different result, that being the connection works. Since you put me on that course, please take your first comment and paste it as the answer along with: It should be ‘db’ instead of ‘localhost’.

Comment: You'll have to refer to the Docker docs for all this. This is core Docker functionality, not specific to Drupal. The internal network in Docker can see containers by their name.